# Java Jackson deserializing with inheritance with builder pattern

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

I have a base class (`Foo`) with 2 children (`A` and `B`). They look like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
  private String fooString;
  public Foo(String fooString) {
    this.fooString = fooString;
  }
  //getter
}

@JsonDeserialize(builder = A.ABuilder.class)
public class A extends Foo {
  private int amount;
  public A(String fooString, int amount) {
    super(fooString);
    this.amount = amount;
  }
  //getter

  @JsonPOJOBuilder
  public static class ABuilder {
    private String fooString;
    private int amount;

    public ABuilder withFooString(final String fooString) {
        this.fooString = fooString;
        return this;
    }

    public ABuilder withAmount(final int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        return this;
    }

    public A build() {
      return new A(fooString, amount);
    }
  }
}

@JsonDeserialize(builder = B.BBuilder.class)
public class B extends Foo {
  private String type;
  public B(String fooString, String type) {
    super(fooString);
    this.type = type;
  }
  //getter

  @JsonPOJOBuilder
  public static class BBuilder {
    private String fooString;
    private String type;

    public BBuilder withFooString(final String fooString) {
        this.fooString = fooString;
        return this;
    }

    public BBuilder withType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
        return this;
    }

    public B build() {
      return new B(fooString, type);
    }
  }
}
```

In my controller I have this endpoint:

```
@PutMapping
private ResponseEntity<Foo> doSomething(@RequestBody Foo dto) {
    //stuff
}
```

But whenever I try to send over my json payload:

```
{
   "fooString":"test",
   "amount":1
}
```

I get the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.Foo` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)"{"fooString":"test","amount":1}; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at AbstractJackson.main(AbstractJackson.java:11)
```

How do I get jackson to deserialize the json into the proper child class? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add empty constructor to abstract Foo class ?

Comment: Also you pasted B class wrong, constructor name should be B, not A.

Comment: I tested it in my local and it does not give an exception, can you share your controller implementation? What data you try to send?

Answer (score -1):

The base class won't get the constructors of the sub classes instead it is quite the opposite,you cannot set subclass specific properties in base class instead you need to use specific subclass for the call or use **custom deserializer for base class** with correct use `intanceOf`
The easiest way to get it working is to change the controller method.

```
@PutMapping
private ResponseEntity<Foo> doSomething(@RequestBody A dto) {
    //stuff
}
```